# how to compare double number with 30 decimal places with the highest precision?

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, nsnumber

i need to compare two big decimal number with 30 decimal places. I need to detect a difference also in the 30th decimal place, so in my needs this:

```
double number_1=80.004752165027610999459284357728;
double number_2=80.004752165027610999459284357727;
```

leads into this:

```
double result = 0.000000000000000000000000000001
```

It seems to be impossible due the nature itself of the number (i have tried with float,long double) . I have only a limited set of decimal places to operate. So in that case how i can achive a better precision? Maybe i can use some framework's function ? I haven't found nothing useful in nsnumber and in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSDecimalNumber`. It should work with up to 38 digits.

> NSDecimalNumber, an immutable subclass of NSNumber, provides an
>   object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. An instance can
>   represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent
>   where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent
>   is an integer from –128 through 127.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber)